# How on ios when launching an application, request permission?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

[image]How on Ios when launching an application, request permission?
Alert window does not appear.

The following settings were made to the Info.plist file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Required for the application to work</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Required for the application to work</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Required for the application to work</string>
```

Alert window does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Location , just adding key-vaule in Info.plist is not enough, also need to request permission when app runtime.

Adding follow code to have a try :

```
CLLocationManager locationManager = new CLLocationManager();

locationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
//Requests permission to use location services while the app is in the foreground.

Or

locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
//Requests permission to use location services whenever the app is running.
```

Here is the [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation?language=objc) , and a [xamarin sample.](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/CoreLocation/)

Comment: When adding code in ...\Views\myfile.cs I get a warning - _unable to find property or namespace CLLocationManager_ Offers to add ```using CoreLocation;``` After adding. I collect application and I receive an error ```Error processing method: 'System.Void System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler / NSUrlSessionDataTaskStream / <ReadAsync> d__14 :: MoveNext ()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be uncertain.```

Comment: @alexandrf Okey , code need to run in IOS ( ViewController.cs or AppDelegate.cs) not in Forms. You can refer to the sample above to see.

Comment: Do I need to add ```using CoreLocation```? In the example "xamarin" I did not find ```using CoreLocation```. My project requires ```using CoreLocation``` when adding code ```CLLocationManager locationManager = new CLLocationManager();

locationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();```

Comment: @alexandrf No, just add `using Foundation;` then `CLLocationManager` can be used.

Comment: @alexandrf Eh,`Core Location` is a Framework, it can be uesd in Xamrin.IOS directly.Actually has nothing to do with other `Using xx`.

Comment: Created a new project -> xamarin-forms -> tabbed template -> get error. add screen.

Comment: Everything works for me if I just add ```using CoreLocation; ``` i use Visual Studio 2019 Preview

Comment: @alexandrf Okey, if can not directly use, add `using CoreLocation` is a choose.If answer be helpful , thanks for marking in advance. :)